# How can get the position of line series in high stock chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

I am using high stock line chart and I am sure I will be having horizontal series data, 
My requirement to show name for each series beside the chart.

I thought High charts won't provide this options So I want to do it manually for that I need the positions for all series in the chart.

Comment: If you need print serie name, you can iterate on each of them and then use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#Renderer.text) to add name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I use the dataLabels functionality to achieve this.

```
dataLabels: {
    enabled: false,
    crop:false,
    overflow:'none',
    align: 'left',
    y:10,
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function() {
        return '<span style="color:'
                +this.series.color+'">'
                +this.series.name+'</span>';
    }
}
```

I set enabled: false in the plot options, and then for the last point of the series, set enabled to true:

```
data:[29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0,{y:176.0,dataLabels:{enabled:true}}]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j8q3o1v2/